# In java, can a method be called/invoked within a loop of another method without using arrays?

Tags: java, loops, methods, return-value

```
public static double numBeers()
{
    String numBeersStr;
    double numBeers;

    numBeersStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many beers would you like?");

    numBeers = Double.parseDouble(numBeersStr);

    if (numBeers < 3 || numBeers > 6)
    {
        numBeersStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You must pick 3-6 beers");
        numBeers = Double.parseDouble(numBeersStr);
    }

    return numBeers;
}

public static double beerPrice(double theBeerBrand)
{

    double beer = 0;
    final double LAGIMRED = 1.90;  
    final double DESINIPA = 2.00;
    final double BELBEBRN = 1.80;
    final double SCHOATST = 2.50;
    final double BOULFHSAISN = 2.75;
    final double GANDANCPRTR = 1.75;


    if (theBeerBrand == 1)
        beer = LAGIMRED;

    else if (theBeerBrand == 2)
        beer = DESINIPA;

    else if (theBeerBrand == 3)
        beer = BELBEBRN;

    else if (theBeerBrand == 4)
        beer = SCHOATST;

    else if (theBeerBrand == 5)
        beer = BOULFHSAISN;

    else 
        beer = GANDANCPRTR;        

    return beer;

}


public static double beerBrand(double theNumBeers )
{   
    String beerTypeStr;
    double count = 1, total = 0, beerType, beeer = 0;

    while (count <= theNumBeers)
    {    
        beerTypeStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose between these fine selections:\n1 - Lagunitas Imperial Red - $1.90\n2 - Deschutes Inversion IPA - $2.00\n3 - Bell's Best Brown Ale - 1.80\n4 - Schlafly's Oatmeal Stout - $2.50" +"\n5 - Boulevard's Farmhouse Saison - $2.75\n6 - Gandy Dancer Porter - $1.75");

            beerType = Double.parseDouble(beerTypeStr);
            // method to be invoked/called------> beeer = beerPrice(beerType);


        count++;
    }    

    total += beeer;

    return total;
```

I'm trying to invoke the beerPrice method within the beerBrand method while loop. Each time the program prompts the user what type of beer they would like, that type of beer is added to the total and then the question is asked again for the same amount of times equivalent to the number of beers the user would like. I'm pretty sure I solved the problem of prompting the user the same number of times equivalent to the number of beers they would like, I'm just not getting the output I desire.

It would be much appreciated if anyone had an idea as how to capture that type of beer and add it to the total so then I'm able to work with the total for discount prices and final prices. I do not want to use any arrays or anything more complicated as this is a practice program for a chapter test that hasn't touched on arrays or the like. Thank you much for any help given.

Comment: Shouldn't `total` be increased be _inside_ the loop?

Comment: EEWW, this code is ugly.  I'd recommend using an enum instead of beerPrice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep that line which is valid:

```
beeer = beerPrice(beerType);
```

However, you need to add the price to your total each time you loop, so bring the corresponding line back into your while:

```
while (count <= theNumBeers) {    
    beerTypeStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
    beerType = Double.parseDouble(beerTypeStr);
    beeer = beerPrice(beerType);
    total += beeer;

    count++;
}
```

It is also good practice to limit the scope of your variables as much as possible - and you while is a `for` really, and I suppose you generally order whole beers, so you could use an `int` instead of a `double` for the number of beers. You could therefoer refactor your method like this:

```
public static double beerBrand(int theNumBeers) {   
    double total = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < theNumBeers; count++) {    
        String beerTypeStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
        double beerType = Double.parseDouble(beerTypeStr);
        total += beerPrice(beerType);
    }

    return total;
}
```

Note: I have not checked the rest of your code.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the additional tip; I'll apply that to the rest of my code.